# How to: overload/ overwrite default CSS for asp:label tag and make it universal in visual studio 2005?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to make a universal CSS layout for a large application my companies working on.  I ran into a problem while trying to style all asp:label's to look a certain way.  I was having the same problem with buttons but I figured that out:

```
input[type="submit"] { 
    background: red;
}
```

that will make all the buttons have a red background....

So, does anyone know how to style asp:label's ??? Everything that I've attempted is listed below, but to no avail:

```
label {
    background: red; 
}

asp:label {
    background: red; 
}

input[type="label"] {
    background: red; 
}
```

Comment: just run your project and check the generated HTML, you will see that a label is simply a span.

Answer (score 2):

Since a label just outputs a span, I would imagine that it's like this:

```
span { background-color:Red; }
```

Comment: you are correct.  I just found this out with firebug also!  So i imagine that panels are treated as divs???